# Use a subclass to modify view of main activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a main activity with `TextViews` and class that want's modify the main activity's `TextViews`.

I keep generating **`NullPointerException`** errors in my `findViewbyID` method in my class.  I'm assuming because I'm not passing the View to the class method.  How do I got about doing this?

Comment: please provide some code so that it can clarify you problem

Comment: You are probably right but, as Singh pointed out, it is nearly impossible to help with a solution if we don't see what you have going on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you will need to to pass Activity instance to your non Activity class using constructor   to access all UI elements from non Activity Class as :

```
public class NonActivity{
Activity activity;
Context context;

public NonActivity(Activity activity,Context context) {
  this.activity=activity;
  this.context=context;
 }

}
```

now you can access UI elements from Activity in NonActivity class as:

```
 TextView textview=(TextView)activity.findViewbyID(R.id.textview);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity , if you use `setcontentView(R.layout.yourlayout)` then all the subsequent `findViewById()` correspond to the views in `yourlayout.xml`.
In the second activity your are trying to find views of the layout of the first activity, that is why you are getting the `NullPointerException`.
Why do you want to manipulate views of this activity in another activity ? I suggest you manipulate the views in the first activity.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't clarify, I was trying to make the changes from an external class to the activity.